# Stabilty of leapfrog scheme applied to wave equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, stability-in-odes

The leapfrog scheme applied to the equation:
$$\frac{dz}{dt} =  \lambda z$$
gives
$$\frac{z^{n+1} - z^{n-1}}{2\Delta t} = \lambda z^n.$$
The region of absolute stability is calculated and it is the pure imaginary interval $-i\leq \lambda \Delta t\leq i$. From that how can I conclude that what are the stability restrictions of the leapfrog scheme applied to the diffusion equation with periodic boundary conditions?